# Documenting multiple possible return types in Swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, nswag

Please consider the following method:

```
[HttpGet("abc")]
public List<BaseClass> GetThemAll()
```

There are 3 types that derive from BaseClass. I would like to provide documentation for the 3 available types.

Q: Is it possible to provide documentation for these 3 derived types (*using NSwag*)?

So far I've tried using `<see` but the *Models* section of Swagger UI does not contain the subtypes.

```
/// <returns>(...) Returned types are: <see cref="TypeA"/>, <see cref="TypeB"/> or <see cref="TypeC"/></returns>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its look like you can describe all derived types via `KnownType`, like:

```
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass1))]
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass2))]
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedClass3))]
public class BaseClass { }
```

Also for visualize inheritance its possible to write own `SchemaProcessor`. For example:

```
  [KnownType(typeof(A))]
  [KnownType(typeof(B))]
  public class BaseType
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }

  public class A : BaseType
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class B : BaseType
  {
    public long A { get; set; }
  }
```

```
[HttpGet("abc")]
public List<BaseType> GetThemAll()
```

```
  public class InheritanceSchemaProcessor : ISchemaProcessor
  {
    public void Process(SchemaProcessorContext context)
    {
      if (context.Type.Name is nameof(BaseType))
      {
        var attributes = context.Type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KnownTypeAttribute), true) as Attribute[];
        foreach (Attribute attribute in attributes)
        {
          var knownTypeAttribute = (KnownTypeAttribute) attribute;
          var schema =
            context.Generator.GenerateWithReference<JsonSchema>(knownTypeAttribute.Type.ToContextualType(), context.Resolver);
          context.Schema.AnyOf.Add(schema);
        }
        
        context.Schema.Properties.Clear();
        context.Schema.AllowAdditionalProperties = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

and in `Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices`:

```
      services.AddOpenApiDocument(s =>
      {
        s.SchemaType = SchemaType.OpenApi3;
        s.SchemaProcessors.Add(new InheritanceSchemaProcessor());
        s.FlattenInheritanceHierarchy = true;
      });
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks! KnownType adds it to the models, but I cannot make the UI show it nicely. That's enough for me for now. I may attack this some time later.

Comment: Any way to do this without Newtonsoft?

Comment: @Magnus, I believe yes, https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/issues/1014